# Require does not work as expected within vm

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, eval, require

The code below uses the native node `vm` library, which allows you to evaluate javascript strings in different contexts.

The particular code within `example.js` there's a javascript string that adds a property `.marker` with the value `true` to the `Array` global variable, then requires a file `global.js` (seen below), then logs `Array.marker`. The code below logs `true`.

```
var vm = require('vm')

var code = [
  'Array.marker = true',
  "require('./global.js')",
  'console.log(Array.marker)', // => true
].join('\n')

var script = new vm.Script(code, { filename: 'example.js' })

script.runInNewContext({
  'require': require,
  'console': console
})
```

Below is the contents of `global.js`, which is a simple module that changes the value of `Array.marker` to `false`.

```
var hi = function () {
  Array.marker = false
}
module.exports = hi()
```

What should be happening here is that the code within the `vm` should be setting `Array.marker` to `true` then the `global.js` module should be changing it the value to `false` and it should log `false`.

If you go ahead and run the contents of the javascript string outside of `vm`, in it's own file, you will get the expected result, `Array.marker` will be equal to `false`.

```
Array.marker = true
require('./global.js')
console.log(Array.marker) // => false
```

The question is: *Why doesn't `Array.marker` get updated to the correct value (`true`)?* *How can I allow the value of `Array.marker` to get updated from within the `global.js` module?*

Is this an issue with the native node.js `vm` module? Or is this not supposed to be possible? Or are my settings off?

**Update:**

I think the bug goes a little deeper. It has more to do with the behavior of the imported `require` then it does with `vm`, to demonstrate that a bit more accurately.

Here I change the value of `Array.marker` from within a new vm context, and you can see it has no effect on the global `Array.marker` after the vm runs. This is expected behavior because I didn't pass anything into `vm`.

```
var vm = require('vm')
var code = [
  'Array.marker = true',
].join('\n')
vm.runInNewContext(code)
console.log(Array.marker) // => undefined [expected]
```

However when I bring `require` into the `vm` something very unexpected happens. The code required maintains the scope of the parent context. So with the given code, you get unexpected results. The global within the vm script `Array.marker` is not changed due to the require call, and you can see the require call is editing the parent scope by setting `Array.marker`.

```
var vm = require('vm')
var code = [
  'Array.marker = true',
  "require(\'./global.js\')",
  'console.log(Array.marker)' // => true [unexpected]
].join('\n')
vm.runInNewContext(code, {
  require: require,
  console: console
})
console.log(Array.marker) // => false [unexpected]
```

The real question is how can instantiate a new instance of `require` within a `vm` rather then importing the parent's? Keeping it localized to the `vm` rather then allowing it to leak into the parent.

Comment: Just a guess, but a different JS context may have an entirely different `Array` object.  So `Array.marker` in one JS context perhaps isn't the same as `Array.marker` in another.

Comment: If you log the value of `Array.marker` after `script.runInNewContext`, you'll see that it's false. My guess is that the `require()` is running in the same context as the "parent".

Comment: @robertklep Right I need a way of require being localized to the context it's in. To put it another way, create another instance of require within the vm script. Any thoughts?

Comment: @ThomasReggi apart from implementing `require()` yourself: no :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
var gbl = require('./global.js');

scriptText = "Array.marker = true; gbl(Array.marker);"

var context = vm.createContext();
var script = vm.createScript(scriptText); 
var fn = script.runInContext(context);
fn(gbl);
```

You would need to change the function in global.js to accept Array.marker as an argument though.